# Options to open new window from HTML

Tags: html

I would like to know various options to open a new URL (website) from the existing website.

I found two ways to show a new site from existing site.

1. Window.open
2. Iframe

Please let me know if there are any other options available to show new site/window.

Thanks
Naresh.D.

Comment: do you want to open a new tab / window with the other website, do you want to include the second website in the first one, or do you want to redirect from the first website to the second ? does there need to be any interaction between the user and the website (the first one) in order to show the second one? could you give an example so we can identify the best options to replicate the desired effect ?

Comment: Yes, It does require interaction between two websites. My requirement is to open second site from first and after doing some operation from second site then again I need to redirect the second site back first site.

Comment: Please make that part of your question, rather than a comment. When you ask a question, always approach it with the mentality of "How much information do I need to give to fully explain my situation?". Try to anticipate possible questions. The more detail you can provide at the beginning (while remaining concise!) the more likely you are to get relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute on links

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

- _blank    Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
- _self     Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
- _parent   Opens the linked document in the parent frame
- _top      Opens the linked document in the full body of the window